# Android Release APK Not Parsing JSON From Web Service with SSL Using Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, apk, retrofit2, android-webservice

I have created a REST web service using SSL, i.e., https://api.bmcstudios.org

The endpoint that I am trying to hit is:

```
GET https://api.bmcstudios.org/member
```

The expected response is

```
{
    "members": [
        {
            "memberId": "5c4e448d46e0fb0001656a46",
            "email": "email@gmail.com",
            "displayName": "username",
            "firstName": "First",
            "lastName": "Last",
            "address": {
                "street_1": "Street Address 1",
                "street_2": "",
                "city": "City",
                "state": "ST",
                "zipCode": 55555,
                "country": "US"
            },
            "phone": "123-456-7890",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": "5c47fe53473d4ad05bdf99f5",
                    "role": "ROLE_MEMBER"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I receive this response when I use Postman, and when I run the Android emulator `Pixel 2 XL API 28`.

When I deploy my build via the Android App Bundle in the latest version of Android Studio 3.3 to the google play store, via the `Internal Test Track` as well as `Production Track` I am able to reach my web service.  But the response that I am returned is empty!

Here are what my logs show as the response:

```
I/System.out: appWebservice.getMemberDetails(): {"members":[{},{},{}]}
```

The structure is present, but the Member object within the array does not show up.  Here is my Java code below:

**Retrofit2 Interface**

```
public interface AppWebservice {
    String API_URL = "https://api.bmcstudios.org/";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                        .create();

    Retrofit RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                                .build();

    // MEMBER
    @GET("member")
    Call<MemberResponse> getMemberDetails(
            @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
}
```

**Member Response Object**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MemberResponse implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("members")
    @Expose
    private List<Member> members;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Member implements Serializable {
        @SerializedName("memberId")
        @Expose
        private String memberId;
        @SerializedName("email")
        @Expose
        private String email;
        @SerializedName("displayName")
        @Expose
        private String displayName;
        @SerializedName("firstName")
        @Expose
        private String firstName;
        @SerializedName("lastName")
        @Expose
        private String lastName;
        @SerializedName("picture")
        @Expose
        private String picture;
        @SerializedName("address")
        @Expose
        private Address address;
        @SerializedName("phone")
        @Expose
        private String phone;
        @SerializedName("roles")
        @Expose
        private List<Role> roles;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @NoArgsConstructor
        public class Address implements Serializable {
            @SerializedName("street_1")
            @Expose
            private String street1;
            @SerializedName("street_2")
            @Expose
            private String street2;
            @SerializedName("city")
            @Expose
            private String city;
            @SerializedName("state")
            @Expose
            private String state;
            @SerializedName("zipCode")
            @Expose
            private Integer zipCode;
            @SerializedName("country")
            @Expose
            private String country;
        }

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @NoArgsConstructor
        public class Role implements Serializable {
            @SerializedName("id")
            @Expose
            private String id;
            @SerializedName("role")
            @Expose
            private String role;
        }
    }
}
```

Making the service call within the app:

```
public void getMemberDetails() {
        if (getIdToken().getValue() == null) {
            updateIdToken();
        } else {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
            headers.put(FIREBASE_AUTH_HEADER, getIdToken().getValue());

            appWebservice.getMemberDetails(headers)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<MemberResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(
                                @NonNull Call<MemberResponse> call,
                                @NonNull retrofit2.Response<MemberResponse> response) {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                System.out.println("appWebservice.getMemberDetails(): " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                                for (MemberResponse.Member member : response.body().getMembers()) {
                                    MemberEntity memberEntity =
                                            toEntity(new Gson().toJson(member));

                                    if (isNotBlank(memberEntity.getMemberId())) {
                                        repository.storeMemberDetails(memberEntity);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(
                                @NonNull Call<MemberResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                            System.err.println("appWebservice.getMemberDetails(): " + t.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

I am not reaching the `onFailure` call because the service call is successful.  I receive a json response, yet it doesn't seem to be parsing correctly, i.e., the data is missing from the objects within the array.

This issue only occurs when I deploy my .apk through the google play store.

Please help me resolve this issue!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This issue was answered here [Gson Not mapping data in Production Mode APK Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282261/gson-not-mapping-data-in-production-mode-apk-android)

add this to your proguard rules

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.example.YourPackage.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using the Gson object called `JsonElement`

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

I swapped out the `MemberResponse` object for the `JsonElement` object and then manually parsed my data via `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`.  It worked out perfectly.

Here are the updated files.

```
public interface AppWebservice {
    String API_URL = "https://api.bmcstudios.org/";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                        .create();

    Retrofit RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                                .build();

    // MEMBER
    @GET("member")
    Call<JsonElement> getMemberDetails(
            @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
}

public void getMemberDetails() {
    if (getIdToken().getValue() == null) {
        updateIdToken();
    } else {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
        headers.put(FIREBASE_AUTH_HEADER, getIdToken().getValue());

        appWebservice.getMemberDetails(headers)
                .enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(
                            @NonNull Call<JsonElement> call,
                            @NonNull retrofit2.Response<JsonElement> response) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            System.out.println("appWebservice.putMemberDetails(): " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                            JsonObject jsonObject = response.body().getAsJsonObject();
                            if (jsonObject.has("members")) {
                                JsonArray members = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("members");
                                for (JsonElement memberElement : members) {
                                    MemberEntity memberEntity =
                                            toEntity(new Gson().toJson(memberElement));

                                    if (isNotBlank(memberEntity.getMemberId())) {
                                        repository.storeMemberDetails(memberEntity);

                                        member.postValue(Member.toMember(memberEntity));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(
                            @NonNull Call<JsonElement> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                        System.err.println("appWebservice.getMemberDetails(): " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```